# Ajax modal popup loads behind the activex control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, activex, modal-dialog, modalpopups

In a page there is an activex control as well as a button whose onclick opens an ajax modal popup. The problem i face is that whenever the button is clicked the ajax pop up loads  behind the activex control and thus it is hidden.So I am not able to use that control at all.
I have not found a proper solution to this. I tried a solution where a browser check condition was removed from the ajaxtoolkit code. but no luck. Am using Ajax toolkit version 3.0.30512.1.let me know if there are any solutions to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any effort to bring a DIV or any HTML element on top of an ActiveX has no effect. An ActiveX stays always on top even if it has higher z-index than an HTML element. The reason is the way the Explorer renders its content. See

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;177378.

There are two types of controls: Windowed and Windowless elements, and they are rendered on separate planes. All windowed elements paint themselves on top of all windowless elements, despite the wishes of their container. However, windowed elements do follow the z-index attribute with respect to each other, just as windowless elements follow the z-index attribute with respect to each other.

All windowless elements are rendered on the same MSHTML plane, and windowed elements draw on a separate MSHTML plane. You can use z-index to manipulate elements on the same plane, but not mix and match with elements in different planes. You can rearrange the z-indexing of the elements on each plane, but the windowed plane always draws on the top of the windowless plane.

The  tag is, in most cases, windowed. That is why it always stays on top.

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct; FireBreath supports creating windowless activex controls, but it's a pain and most controls don't support it because the control doesn't get its own HWND.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience of ActiveX, but this could be a simple CSS Z-Index positioning issue. Have you ensured that the Z-Index of your control is lower than that of the modal popup?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think the problem is the ActiveX, which is always displayed at topmost.

You could try to hide the ActiveX when displaying the popup:

```
document.getElementById('activex').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

and then when you close the popup show the ActiveX again:

```
document.getElementById('activex').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, try setting the width and height to 1; some ActiveX controls may behave strangely if you make them actually invisible because the browser may deactivate the control.  Lenciel's answer is absolutely what is going on here -- I couldn't have explained it better myself.

Comment: its been a long time since i posted this question and was surprised to see a comment now. :)
We actually changed the page flow a bit to make this activex as the single control on the page.at that time it was a quick fix to get the site delivered.